# Error when passing macro to \setmainlanguage

Tags: xetex, luatex, polyglossia

Error when compiling this example using vanilla XeLaTeX (`XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022)`) or LuaLaTeX (`This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)`).

I've got the following class `test.cls`:

```
\ProvidesClass{test}[2022/05/06 Test class]
\DeclareOption{portuguese}{\def\my@mainlanguage{portuguese}}
\DeclareOption{english}{\def\my@mainlanguage{english}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\ExecuteOptions{}
\LoadClass{article}\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{\my@mainlanguage}
```

And a sample document:

```
\documentclass[portuguese]{test}
\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitleTest
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type  H <return>  for immediate help. ...

l.8 \setmainlanguage{\my@mainlanguage}
```

It compiles with no errors using TeXLive from 2021.

Comment: It works-ish for me (`\maketitleTest` is undefined and throws an error) if I expand the language name before `polyglossia` gets to see it with `\expandafter\setmainlanguage\expandafter{\my@mainlanguage}`. If you think `polyglossia` should try to expand the language name itself, you can file an issue at https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues (especially if this used to work correctly), but these kind of things are always tricky. (If `polyglossia` does not do expansion, it might still be good to at least document that.)

Comment: @moewe using an old version of TeX Live works fine... so I don't know of `polyglossia` changed something or maybe it is another error...

Comment: Now at https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/543